# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Twig\\Extension\\AbstractExtension' not found

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I've tried updating Symfony to v2.8.* today.

I have this error:

> Fatal error:  Class 'Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension' not found

Please help

Here my composer json :

```
"name": "assane/myecomapp",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3,>=2.3.10",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "twig/extensions":"*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3"
},
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 3 Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension not found error in production mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446199/symfony-3-twig-extension-abstractextension-not-found-error-in-production-mode)

Comment: Do you see the file exists in `vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/AbstractExtension.php`?

Comment: Yes the file exists :

Comment: root@KiraLinux:/var/www/html/myecomapp# ls vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/AbstractExtension.php
vendor/twig/twig/src/Extension/AbstractExtension.php
root@KiraLinux:/var/www/html/myecomapp#

Comment: did you try to clear the cache?

Comment: Yes It's done now

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me when I aborted `composer install`. Clearing cache didn't help, but here's how I managed to make it work:

- remove all packages in `vendor`
- run `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

The generated cache is out of date then remove it and refresh the web page:

```
sudo rm -R app/cache/*
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about your answer - how did you know that this is the cause for a problem that is two years old?

Comment: I know it because I'm working on a old symfony2.8 project. The cache in prod mode is generated during the loading page. I suppose the project is in prod mode so if the command `php app/console cache:clear` is executed, it will work only for dev mode

Comment: But since when did that cache contain a composer autoloader?

Comment: The autoloader is in `vendor` folder. The autoloader ask to load the the file `app/cache/classe.php` the file `classe.php` is out of date so it asks to load a wrong extension.